# Reusing Environment from a different project's SConstruct

Tags: python, scons

I have been given a completed source archive (call it `legacyProject`) that has a `SConstruct` build script.  This build script does a lot of work to create a nice customized `Environment` that understands a custom toolchain for a microcontroller.  It also has a couple of helper functions that simplify the generation of `Program` statements for a rather large build matrix.

I am starting a related project that could reuse this `Environment` and related code almost verbatim.  I don't want to just copy-paste everything into a new SConstruct file, because the original might receive patches (not to mention that it's simply duplication of code).  Currently these projects are side-by-side in the filesystem:

```
myProject/
    SConstruct
legacyProject/
    SConstruct
```

I'll probably rearrange them so that `legacyProject` is a subdirectory of `myProject`, so I can track exact revisions with version control.

```
myProject/
    SConstruct
    legacyProject/
        SConstruct
```

**Is there a way to import all the code from `legacyProject/SConstruct`?**  With Python modules, this is trivial with `import`, but I don't know if this is possible with Scons.  My attempt:

```
SConscript('legacyProject/SConstruct')
```

just returns None.

Comment: you got a `__init__.py` in `legacyProject` folder ?

Comment: No, just the SConstruct file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without refactoring some of the functionality from the legacy SConstruct into a helper file, I don't believe there is a way to do this.

If you can refactor the code out, then there are three possible alternatives approaches available - one is to use the existing SConscript mechanism built into SCons, another is to use python modules and the final approach is to use the site-dir option.

**Reuse Via SConscripts**

Assuming a project structure like:

```
.
├── common
│   └── SConscript
├── legacyProject
│   └── SConstruct
└── myProject
    └── SConstruct
```

Your SConstruct files will create an environment, then execute the `common/SConscript`, which returns a modified environment. For example, if you wanted to collect some options in the common directory you might end up with something like:

```
# common/SConscript
Import('env')
env['CCFLAGS']  = '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'
Return('env')
```

And

```
# myProject/SConstruct (similar for legacy/SConstruct)
env = Environment()
print 'before:', env['CCFLAGS']
env = SConscript('../common/SConscript', exports = 'env')
print 'after:', env['CCFLAGS']
```

*pick this approach if:*

- you're familiar with SCons, but less familiar with Python
- you don't want to pass extra flags to scons or set environment variables
- you're trying to be agnostic of which installation of Python you're using
- you're not using variant directories

**Reuse via Python Modules**

If you're going to package scons utilities as python packages, there are two routes you can take.

The first is to use traditional Python packaging techniques. There are some good guides around - I recommend the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/). To get this working you'll need to write a [setup.py](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#setup-py), and installing using either `pip` or `python setup.py install`

What makes this tricky is that you can have multiple side-by-side installations of Python and SCons, which are subtly coupled through your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable.  This may mean something that works on one machine may not work on another machine.

A more common approach is to modify the path python uses to search for modules in your SConstructs - poor practice from a Python perspective, but slightly more maintainable, particularly if your build machines are complex.

Assuming a project structure like:

```
.
├── common
│   └── __init__.py
├── legacyProject
│   └── SConstruct
└── myProject
    └── SConscript
```

Your python module can be quite simple:

```
# common/__init__.py
def set_warning_flags(env):
    env['CCFLAGS']  = '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'
```

And:

```
# myProject/SConstruct
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
import common

env = Environment()
print 'before:', env['CCFLAGS']
common.set_warning_flags(env)
print 'after:', env['CCFLAGS']
```

*Pick this approach if:*

- you have a lot of external configuration (many builders / complex environments) that only need to be pulled in from a few places.
- you aren't using variant builds

**Reuse Via site-dir / site-init**

If you want to add functionality on the fly to multiple SConstructs without changing them, you can use the in-built extensibility supported by SCons (see the sections in the user manual [Where To Put Your Custom Builders and Tools](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#idm140113664596608) or search for `--site-dir=dir` in the [SCons Man Page](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html)

In this case you would have:

```
.
├── common
│   └── site_init.py
├── legacyProject
│   └── SConstruct
└── myProject
    └── SConstruct
```

Where `site_init.py` was:

```
# common/site_init.py
def set_warning_flags(env):
    env['CCFLAGS']  = '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'
```

And the SConstruct was:

```
env = Environment()
print 'before:', env['CCFLAGS']
set_warning_flags(env)
print 'after:', env['CCFLAGS']
```

But you need to invoke SCons (from the myProject / legacyProject directories) with:

```
scons --site-dir=../common
```

*Pick this approach if:*

- you want to make changes to both projects builds without changing the code for either.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the options!  I think the first method is probably most useful in the simple case where I just want to modify the Environment.  However, refactoring into modules is probably better if I need to reuse functions in both legacy and myProject.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest re-engineering the logic you want to share into a python module you import and call some initialization in your SConstruct. This would be the cleanest method (IMHO).

While you can use pythons execfile() (I believe), it's a messy way to go about this.